# Dump SQLite query result to XML

Tags: php, xml, sqlite

I am trying to query a SQLite DB and dump the result to xml. Here is the code:

```
    $db = new SQLite3("terrapin");
$db->exec($insert);

$select = "select * from information";
$results=$db->query($select);
while($result=$results->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
{
        $xml.="<username>".$result['username']."</username>\n";
        $xml.="<latitude>".$result['latitude']."</latitude>\n";
        $xml.="<longtitude>".$result['longtitude']."</longtitude>\n";
        $xml.="<timestamp>".$result['timestamp']."</timestamp>\n";
        $xml.="<filename>".$result['filename']."</filename>\n";
}
```

When I do a `print_r($xml)`, PHP prints out all values but does not show tags. I am trying to use the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613966/sqlite-to-xml-via-php). What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because tags is interpreted as html tags so you wont see them, view source to see them.
What you need to do is provide

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

And send correct response headers to browser that its xml to HTML

```
header ("Content-Type:text/xml");
echo $xml;
exit;
```

Also you are missing root element.